# "Error: Class FrontEndBundle\Entity\MarcaAuto has no association named id" en Symfony 3, al especificar una asociación en dos entidades

Tags: symfony3, doctrine

Tengo dos entidades MarcaAuto y ModeloAuto con la siguiente definición:

**MarcaAuto**

```
<?php

namespace FrontEndBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MarcaAuto
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="marcas_auto")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FrontEndBundle\Repository\MarcaAutoRepository")
 */
class MarcaAuto
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ModeloAuto", mappedBy="idMarca")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $marca;
```

**ModeloAuto**

```
<?php

namespace FrontEndBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ModeloAuto
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="modelos_auto")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FrontEndBundle\Repository\ModeloAutoRepository")
 */
class ModeloAuto {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_marca", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MarcaAuto", inversedBy="id")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_marca", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $idMarca;
```

Al hacer un select sobre la entidad en mi controlador de esta forma:

**AcmeController**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT a
                FROM FrontEndBundle:MarcaAuto a
                LEFT JOIN a.id
                ORDER BY a.marca ASC'
        );

        $marcasVehiculos = $query->getResult();
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 68 near 'ORDER BY a.marca': Error:
>   Class FrontEndBundle\Entity\MarcaAuto has no association named id 500
>   Internal Server Error - QueryException 1 linked Exception:
>   QueryException »

He revisado la documentación una y otra vez y no logro dar con el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucioné mi problema de la siguiente manera, aunque desconozco cual es la razón de por que no funciona con el ejemplo inicial.

Quité la siguiente línea de la entidad ModeloAuto:

```
* @ORM\Column(name="id_marca", type="integer")
```

Con lo anterior se generó un foreign key en la tabla "modelos_autos" que antes no se generaba al llamar el comando: "php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force"

Cambié el select a:

```
 'SELECT a
                FROM FrontEndBundle:ModeloAuto a
                LEFT JOIN a.idMarca b
                '
```

Al parecer hay algun tipo de problema al intentar generar una asociación a otra tabla cuando el atributo es un primary key.

**Edicion 1**

Logré identificar el problema de mi pregunta original y esta es la solución:

**MarcaAuto:**

```
/**
 * MarcaAuto
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="marcas_auto")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FrontEndBundle\Repository\MarcaAutoRepository")
 */
class MarcaAuto {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ModeloAuto", mappedBy="idMarca")
     */
    private $modelos;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $marca;
```

**ModeloAuto:**

```
/**
 * ModeloAuto
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="modelos_auto")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FrontEndBundle\Repository\ModeloAutoRepository")
 */
class ModeloAuto {

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MarcaAuto", inversedBy="modelos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_marca", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $idMarca;
```

**AcmeController:**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT a, b
                FROM FrontEndBundle:MarcaAuto a
                LEFT JOIN a.modelos b
                '
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu `LEFT JOIN` tiene error:

```
SELECT a
                FROM FrontEndBundle:MarcaAuto a
                LEFT JOIN a.id
                ORDER BY a.marca ASC
```

no le dices al SQL con qué quieres hacer el JOIN:

```
LEFT JOIN a.id ON  #... La otra tabla y la columna donde quieres hacer JOIN
```

Comment: Me da la impresión de que no es necesario al crear queries DQL, al menos en la documentación de Doctrine así lo especifica http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html. ¿Cómo seria el query completo con lo que tu indicas?

Comment: En realidad no uso DQL, pero el mensaje de error te dice claramente esto `Class FrontEndBundle\Entity\MarcaAuto has no association named id` de lo que deduzco que, o el `JOIN`está mal, o que la variable `a.id`no existe. Busca por ese lado, es lo que dice tu mensaje de error.

Comment: Por algún motivo tu clase `MarcaAuto`no está reconociendo el valor de `id`... ¿Problema de anotación?

Comment: Es ahi donde realmente tengo la duda ya que la anotación para esa clase especifica: `* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ModeloAuto", mappedBy="idMarca")`

Comment: ¿Has probado a cambiar `idMarca`por `id` o viceversa? Veo en el código también otro campo llamado `id_marca`... revisa un poco de ese lado.

Comment: Si, de hecho segui el ejemplo de la documentación original de Doctrine: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional. Lo que reclama Symfony no es que la asociación esté mal hecha, si no que, no existe asociación, siendo que claramente se especifica para el atributo id.

Comment: Huele a un error de anotación en cualquier parte. ¿`id`no debería estar anotado al principio de la clase `MarcaAuto`?

Comment: Está: `* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")`

Comment: A. Si pruebas a usar `id_marca` en el SELECT ¿que pasa? B. Si quitas el `ORDER BY a.marca ASC` de la consulta ¿qué pasa? Desde el principio intuía que el mensaje de error señala un error en tu SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine no es igual a PDO al menos que sea una Query personalizada podrías acceder al objeto checa este enlace a mi me ayudó a resolver ese problema,
https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony2-ep3/doctrine-relationship 
se accede a la base de datos como si fueran objetos, si fuera correcto podrías acceder simplemente como si fuera un objeto sin necesidad de hacer un Query con DQL. igual podrías desde la consola actualizar el esquema de tu base de datos para que concuerde con tus entidades.